# css height calc when scroll is active

Tags: css, sass

I have a container in which there is a spinner composed by a spin and background. It works well except when I enter in a new page where the scroll(overflow-y) is active.
It shows the background up to half.
Here is the piece of code

```
<div class="container-fullheight" id="route-container">
  <spinner></spinner>
  <div class="container-fluid px-3">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>

@media (min-width: 992px) {
   .container-fullheight {
      height: calc(100vh - 140px);
   }
}
```

I tried to remove the **height: calc(100vh - 140px);** but in this way when I enter in the page the spinner starts and it's shown on top of the page and not in the center.

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: code provided by you is not enough to understand your issue please share full code here or on codepan, fiddle, etc. so that we can get your issue

Comment: unfortunatly I can't share the code or create a case. it's part of other projects

Comment: So I think no one can help you with this code.

Comment: I added a picture to see the problem

Comment: Set `position: fixed` on spinner

Comment: unfortunantly it doesn't work